# Elasticsearch term query with must and should

Tags: elasticsearch

**In the question,the fields "slovenian" and "slovakian" and "german" must have "street" field, but the field "turkish" doesn't have "street" field. When i run my query I want also the docs that have "turkish" fields' datas in this order**. But I don't want another docs that have "nation" fields in this order.

Below is my query, If i run the query, I don't get values of the docs that have "turkish" field. When I remove "street" in must,I get the values of the docs that have "turkish" field but I also get another docs that are don't have "street" fields.

```
{
        "sort": [
            {
                "index_number.numeric": {
                    "order": "asc"
                }
            }
        ],
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "street": {
                                "value": street_val
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": gte,
                                "lt": lte
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "nation": "slovenian"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "nation": "slovakian"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "nation": "german"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "nation": "turkish"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }

                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

**As an example, (test case)**
I want to fetch "nation" is "slovenian" or "slovakian" or "german" or "turkish" but "slovenian" and "slovakian" and "german" must have "street_field", but "turkish" doesn't have "street" field. I mean fetch all if "slovenian" or "slovakian" or "german" if it has "street" field, and fetch "turkish" but "turkish" doesn't matter if it has a "street" field or not. And do not fetch the others. Finaly sort them via "index_number".

```
  ....
  ... "index_number": 30, "nation": "turkish" ...
  ... "index_number": 210, "nation": "slovenian", "street": "slovenia_street_name" ...
  ... "index_number": 13, "nation": "slovakian", "street": "slovakia_street_name" ...
  ... "index_number": 21, "nation": "italian", "street": "italia_street_name" ...
  ... "index_number": 51, "nation": "german", "street": "german_street_name" ...
  ... "index_number": 13, "nation": "syrian" ...
  ... "index_number": 52, "nation": "french" ...
  ...
```

**After running the query, I want my search results would be similar like below** Expected result is below.

```
...
doc => ... "index_number": 13, "nation": "slovakian", "street": "slovakia_street_name" ...
doc => ... "index_number": 30, "nation": "turkish" ...
doc => ... "index_number": 51, "nation": "german", "street": "german_street_name" ...
doc => ... "index_number": 210, "nation": "slovenian", "street": "slovenia_street_name" ...
...
```

How can i do this ? Can someone give an example ?
Thanks for answering

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: I have edited this question and I made e example test case for this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html) to achieve your use case

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "nation": "slovenian"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "nation": "slovakian"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "nation": "german"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "street"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "nation": "turkish"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "index_number": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

Using the same sample index data (As provided in the question), the search result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65804647",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "index_number": 13,
          "nation": "slovakian",
          "street": "slovakia_street_name"
        },
        "sort": [
          13
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "65804647",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "index_number": 30,
          "nation": "turkish"
        },
        "sort": [
          30
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "65804647",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "index_number": 51,
          "nation": "german",
          "street": "german_street_name"
        },
        "sort": [
          51
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "65804647",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "index_number": 210,
          "nation": "slovenian",
          "street": "slovenia_street_name"
        },
        "sort": [
          210
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I have upvoted and accepted the answer. Thank you so much. Thats the answer I'm looking for